# How to implement a macro to apply a template repeatedly with some common and some varying arguments

Tags: nim-lang

The use case is the following: I have a config object and a main object. Main object contain a field of config type. Config object has many fields and I want to make them accessible from main object as if they were fields of main object.

Here is a toy example that show the intended api:

```
type
  MyCfg = object
    text: string
    number: int
  MyObj = object
    myCfg: MyCfg
    otherField: bool

template expose(ObjType, cfg, field, FieldType: untyped) =
  template `field`(o: ObjType): FieldType =
    o.`cfg`.`field`

expose MyObj, myCfg, text, string

var obj = MyObj()
obj.myCfg.text = "hi"
echo obj.text

macro expose(ObjType, myCfg, body: untyped) =
  discard


expose(ObjType, myCfg):
  (text, string) # even better if I can avoid parenthesis
  (number, int)
```

As shown above, I know how to do a `template` that exposes the field, I know how to wrap it in a template that simplifies the syntax, I have not yet learned how to use a macro to repeatedly apply the template where the first arguments are always the same and I give the varying arguments in the following lines.

**edit**: this commit makes probably a bit more explicit my intent: https://github.com/pietroppeter/nimibook/pull/50/commits/9edf5e351713db61cabb6d4aa0c740f31ba537c4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works

```
import std/[genasts, macros]

type
  MyCfg = object
    text: string
    number: int
  MyObj = object
    myCfg: MyCfg
    otherField: bool

macro expose(t: typed, childObject: untyped) =
  for field in t.getimpl[2][2]:
    if field[0] == childObject:
      result = newStmtList()
      for subfield in field[1].getimpl[2][2]:
        result.add:
          genast(subfieldName = subfield[0], ParentObject = t, SubfieldType = subfield[1], childObject = childObject):
            proc subfieldName(o: ParentObject): SubfieldType =
              o.childObject.subfieldName

MyObj.expose(myCfg)

var myObj = MyObj()
myObj.myCfg.text = "text"
myObj.myCfg.number = 1234567890

echo myObj.text
echo myObj.number
```

Comment: very nice, thanks! with this I do not even specify which field (in some cases I might want to have control over which field to expose, but in this case I do not). I adapted to use template and to support also the setter. Given the code you shared, very straightforward: https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=3Scp